# Reducing duplication in code

Tags: java

I currently have multiple code like this for different toppings

```
// Toppings - Egg
System.out.print("Do you want " + egg.getType() + "?");
input = keyboard.nextLine();
choice = input.charAt(0);
if (choice == 'y') {
    l.add(egg.getType());
    c.add((double) egg.getCost());
    numberOfToppings = numberOfToppings + 1;
    totalToppingPrice = totalToppingPrice + egg.getCost();
    toppings = toppings + "Egg";
}
```

It works fine, however i was hoping i could do all toppings in just one block of code. Because i've got around 5 of these, and it takes up far too much, and i've been advised to do so. Anyone got any ideas for how this could be done ? thanks

Comment: Make a method that does all the work, pass variables into the method for the things that change each time. Then call the method with the appropriate values five times.

Comment: Just use the "Extract method" feature of your IDE. And check out other stuff there as well, because they sure come in handy.

Comment: In order to fulfill Open/Closed principle => replace primitive (`choice`) with object to get polymorphism with strategy/state pattern

Comment: To expand on Jespers fine suggestion: the method should do stuff for one given *topping*.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you make a Topping class that you can use as follows:

```
Toppping egg = new Topping ("egg", 0.5); // Cost
ArrayList<Topping> toppings = new ArrayList<Topping>();
toppings.add(egg);
```

Later you can loop over the toppings vector similar to this:

```
for (Topping current : toppings) {
  if (wantsTopping(current)) {
     chosenToppings.addObject(current);
  }
}
```

Note: This is Java like code, but it won't compile. There are still some things you need to look up

Comment: I know that it's not java code, but you can really confuse java beginner by: 1. using Vector instead of ArrayList. 2. Using raw generics (without <>)

Comment: Your right, I updated the code to use ArrayList. My Java is a bit rusty

Answer (score 1):

All the toppings should be gathered together in an enumeration, as long as the topping set is closed and cannot change during the program execution.

```
enum Topping{
    EGG("egg", 22),... ;
    private String type;
    private double cost;

    private Topping(String type, double cost){
        this.type = type;
        this.cost = cost;
    }
    //getters and setters

}
```

Then, you could write a method inside your class containing your code above that should be able to handle a `Topping` instance, like this:

```
private handleTopping(Topping top){
    System.out.print("Do you want "+top.getType() +"?");
    input = keyboard.nextLine();
    choice = input.charAt(0);
    if (choice == 'y'){
        l.add(top.getType());
        c.add(top.getCost());
        numberOfToppings = numberOfToppings + 1;
        totalToppingPrice = totalToppingPrice + top.getCost();
        toppings = toppings + " " + top.getType();
    }
}
```

Finally, call the method for all toppings available

```
for(Topping top : topping.values()){
    handleTopping(top);
}
```

It's all about the DRY (don't repeat yourself principle). It's not even necessarily tied to the object oriented paradigm. Even in procedural programming, one of the core principles is to extract common and frequently used functionalities to parameterized procedures.

Comment: can't use enum unfortunately :(

Comment: Why not? Anyway, in that case, make it a regular class instead of an enum.